# AWS Cognito authorizer not working with AWS SDK for Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-android

In my Android project, I use the AWS SDK to register users thanks to Cognito and call APIs in API Gateway. In my Cognito user pool, I created a user pool group. The purpose of that group is to only allow the users in that group to call a specific API.

In order to make it work, I try to follow [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-group/) (especially the video). So I created a Cognito authorizer, added it to my method request in API Gateway, and try to call the API from my app using the AWS SDK:

```java
@Service(endpoint = "https://abcdefghig.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/staging")
public interface AwsdemoapiClient
{
    @Operation(path = "/test-api", method = "GET")
    Empty testApiGet(); 
}
```

The problem is: whether the user is authenticated or not, and in the group or not, I always get the following error, when I call `testApiGet()` in my app: `401 Unauthorized`, even if I have the right authorization in my IAM roles. After some research, it looks like the id token is missing, which could be the reason why I get that error.

But isn't it supposed to be automatically managed by the AWS SDK for Android? How can I fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the id token in the header actually solved the problem:

```java
@Service(endpoint = "https://abcdefghig.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/staging")
public interface AwsdemoapiClient
{
    @Operation(path = "/test-api", method = "GET")
    Empty testApiGet(@Parameter(name = "Authorization", location = "header") String idToken);; 
}
```

You can get the id token by calling the following function:

```java
CognitoUserPool pool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolId, clientId, clientSecret, region);
pool.getCurrentUser().getSessionInBackground(...);
```